# Siege to capture only final statistics

Tags: linux, performance, command, loadrunner, siege

I have a requirement to capture final statistics of siege benchmark tool.
what I have tried is

```
siege -c2 -t10s http://127.0.0.1:3000/ > siege.log 2>&1
```

but siege.log has many `HTTP/1.1 200     0.00 secs:      16 bytes ==> GET  /` aswel with it.

All i want is final statistics like below

```
Lifting the server siege...
Transactions:                496 hits
Availability:             100.00 %
Elapsed time:               0.97 secs
Data transferred:           0.01 MB
Response time:              0.00 secs
Transaction rate:         511.34 trans/sec
Throughput:             0.01 MB/sec
Concurrency:                1.82
Successful transactions:         496
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:            0.04
Shortest transaction:           0.00
```

Please suggest. Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure, why there is a down vote for the question?

Comment: Perhaps because (a) it lists a tool which is not part of the question, (ii) it shows no effort on the part of the user to consolidate the data, & (3) not a programming question/its a tool question

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in a hard way.

By default, at `$HOME/.siege/siege.conf` has `verbose` set to true.

Option 1:
One can override it to false at `$HOME/.siege/siege.conf`

Option 2:
if you prefer to not to change global configuration, One can create a custom siege configuration and run as below

```
siege -c2 -t10s http://127.0.0.1:3000/ --rc=siege.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tail -n`,

```
$ siege -c2 -t10s http://127.0.0.1:3000/ | tail -n 15
```